# 240v panel-no neutral

Tags: grounding, subpanel, 240v, neutral

This is the culmination of a few posts ([Disconnecting 240 hots without disconnecting neutral?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/252056/98760), [240v only subpanel, no ground?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/252058/98760)) to see if this seems right.

I had a subpanel A with 20A double pole breaker leading to a set of baseboard heaters. I wanted to run a 40A subpanel from that breaker position instead. I disconnected the two blue wires running to the heaters, replaced with a 40A breaker, and ran 8 AWG wire to the subpanel which is shown below. This is for 240v only, I will label the panel such, but does this look correct, hot/hot/ground without a neutral connection? (Realizing I should black wrap the white wire to the circuit breaker to indicate a hot leg)

Initially, there was concern the first subpanel wasn't adequately grounded so I ran an 8 or 10 AWG (I think 8) from subpanel A to the original main breaker ground/neutral bar).

Thanks for any thoughts!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do not know enough, but I would have thought that the second(white) hot mount would have been more protected from fingers(like the black hot).  It looks more like a neutral mounting screw.  If you are getting 240 from it, I guess it is okay, just looks odd to me.

Comment: Several comments:  You are limiting future flexibility (IE 120V) circuits by not having a neutral.  Next, you didn't need to use white wires to the 240 V outlets, two blacks would have been better.  Next: you used romex clamps, you should have used bushings instead, I doubt using romex clams on individual wires is up to code.  Next:  you have 4 (FOUR) NEMA 6-20R recept. on one 20 amp circuit.  What are you planning to use those for? Seems terribly under powered.

Comment: ALL the white wires need to be wrapped with tape, paint or shrink tube to indicate their use as a hot. The #8 feeder and all the #12/14 branches.  On both ends.  Unadorned whites are never allowed to be hot wires.   This rule was tightened up in the last 10 years or so, so you might have learned it different.

Comment: What country is this, some strange choice of wires colors.

Comment: I have never been called on a white on a 240 branch circuit but I do normally mark 6” at each splice or termination in some cases a black line from a sharpie. I have had an inspector say it was a waste of time in the panel as someone that did not realize a wire connected to a breaker was hot should not be in the panel, I do agree with that but at splice points and terminations they should be marked for at least 6”.

Comment: @knowitall those are standard US colors it looks like a conduit job.

Comment: @EdBeal did not know that, strange using white as phase, it needs special (black tape marking)

Comment: @knowitall read the question it clearly stated that the whites needed marking.

Comment: Azulith, where are the baseboards located?  Do they have any receptacles on them? What state are you in.

Comment: @knowitall  Quite common to use white as a second hot if in a cable and you do not need a neutral.  It is uncommon if separate wires in a conduit.

Answer (score 1):

Other than the wire marking issue you have identified (ALL whites used for hot, not just feeders must be marked on both ends), it looks fine.

The very short links between the panel and those outlets are a perfect job for a short nipple of EMT conduit.  The EMT carries the ground to the metal box for you, so you only need 2 wires.   I work 98% in EMT and I don't even own any green wire lol.